# Filters for visio diagram based on the user input

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, visio, integrate-remedy-sp2013

I have data in a `SP external list`, one of the fields holds a date. I would like to visually present this data using `Visio` Services.

I have drawn the Visio diagram using `visio 2013` and using `visio WebPart` I was able to put in the SharePoint 2013 page, but the challenge is now we need to filter the date in the list and expecting the Visio diagram to change the data based on the date.

For example : Below is the data which is present in the list and being used for Visio for its diagram. Now using a date filter if we filter the Date as 2/23/2015, then we need to change the count for only for 'F'. based on the date filter the data in the Visio needs to be filtered.

How we can achieve this?

[image: Example table from which the visio diagram is created]

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the answer for this issue in the below link. please let me know if you have any queries on this.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/017e350b-4558-415b-9ebc-54db643fba81/filters-for-visio-digram-based-on-the-user-input

Comment: Please describe the solution in more depth on this site as well.